# STS- Add Server - Next Button is disabled when I try to add oracle weblogic server

Tags: eclipse, ide, spring-tool-suite, weblogic-10.x, eclipse-wtp

I am facing issue in adding oracle weblogic sever in sts. when I go to Windows -> Preferences -> Server Runtime and try to add oracle weblogic server the next button is disabled.

what is the resolution of this problem?

**Edit:-**

Error logs are as follows

> Unhandled event loop exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
>   1.6
>
> at org.eclipse.sapphire.Version.(Version.java:77)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.sapphire.VersionConstraint.check(VersionConstraint.java:373)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.util.JdtUtil$JvmValidator.version(JdtUtil.java:149)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerRuntime.validateVMPath(WeblogicServerRuntime.java:202)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerRuntime.getDefaultJavaVmLocation(WeblogicServerRuntime.java:254)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerRuntime.getJavaVmLocation(WeblogicServerRuntime.java:363)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerRuntime.validate(WeblogicServerRuntime.java:142)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.ui.server.internal.WeblogicServerRuntimeWizardFragment.validateImpl(WeblogicServerRuntimeWizardFragment.java:183)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.ui.server.internal.WeblogicServerRuntimeWizardFragment.validate(WeblogicServerRuntimeWizardFragment.java:175)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.ui.server.internal.BaseWizardFragment.updateFragment(BaseWizardFragment.java:146)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.ui.server.internal.WeblogicServerRuntimeWizardFragment$3.modifyText(WeblogicServerRuntimeWizardFragment.java:280)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:179)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1118)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.wmCommandChild(Text.java:3071)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_COMMAND(Control.java:4824)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4679)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5050)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2443)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(Text.java:260)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2671)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5050)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowTextW(Native Method)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowText(OS.java:3473)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Text.java:2296)
>
> at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.ui.server.internal.WeblogicServerRuntimeWizardFragment$5.widgetSelected(WeblogicServerRuntimeWizardFragment.java:314)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
>
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
>
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.RuntimePreferencePage.showWizard(RuntimePreferencePage.java:396)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.RuntimePreferencePage$2.widgetSelected(RuntimePreferencePage.java:146)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
>
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
>
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:211)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:63)
>
> at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
>
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
>
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
>
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)

Comment: Maybe STS is too old to recognize the newer server runtime. Which versions do you use?

Comment: weblogic version is 10.3 and sts version is 3.7.2

Comment: Does installing [Oracle WebLogic Server Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/oracle-weblogic-server-tools) fix your issue? The server runtimes are supported via [Eclipse WTP Server Tools](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/server/), not directly via STS.

Comment: I had already installed Oracle WebLogic Server Tools in my sts. still facing the issue

Comment: I tried this using the latest STS 3.9.8 CI builds as well as the latest Eclipse 2018-12 release, installed the Weblogic Server Tools from the Eclipse marketplace, and it looks like I can select Weblogic as a server and press next. Can you double check with those versions of STS and Eclipse to see if that helps?

Comment: ok will do that. appreciate your efforts

Comment: kindly see my edited question